# Missing $ inserted with \left and \right

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

Hello everybody I am a new Latex user and I try to write a my first presentation starting from a templete.
When I try to make a slide with this code

```
\subsection{Main Result}
\frame
{
\begin{block}{Theorem \left[ Pasquale, Nicola \right]}
Consider the multiplex network .... code from daniel
\end{block}
}
```

I have this error

```
Missing $ inserted.}
```

Thanks a lot for every answer

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Whoever told you that you always need `\left` and `\right` in front of `[` and `]` (or other brackets) was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to not use `\left` and `\right`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\frame
{
\begin{block}{Theorem [Pasquale, Nicola]}
Consider the multiplex network .... code from daniel
\end{block}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However if you want to use `\left` and `\right` you should be in math mode **but this is not the best solution at all**:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\frame
{
\begin{block}{Theorem $\left[\text{Pasquale, Nicola} \right]$}
Consider the multiplex network .... code from daniel
\end{block}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You really don't want to write a name in math mode like that. The interword space is ignored (edit: but you get a small space after the comma), and the character spacing will be wrong.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. With a `\text` it's better of course

Comment: Yes, but rather pointless, isn't it?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I agree `:-)`